# Strings written to file do not preserve line breaks

Tags: java, string, file, newline

I am trying to write a `String`(lengthy but wrapped), which is from `JTextArea`. When the string printed to console, formatting is same as it was in `Text Area`, but when I write them to file using BufferedWriter, it is writing that `String` in single line.

Following snippet can reproduce it:

```
public class BufferedWriterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String string = "This is lengthy string that contains many words. So\nI am wrapping it.";
        System.out.println(string);
        File file = new File("C:/Users/User/Desktop/text.txt");
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        bufferedWriter.write(string);
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
}
```

What went wrong? How to resolve this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: were the size of your console and the size of your JTeaxtArea the same?

Comment: if not, then probably its because you need \r\n for windows new line

Comment: Eclipse Console and JTextArea is 750x400 px. If I have to add \r\n, how do I do for input from JTextArea? Is it possible to identify line breaks?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Text from a `JTextArea` will have `\n` characters for newlines, regardless of the platform it is running on.  You will want to replace those characters with the platform-specific newline as you write it to the file (for Windows, this is `\r\n`, as others have mentioned).

I think the best way to do that is to wrap the text into a `BufferedReader`, which can be used to iterate over the lines, and then use a `PrintWriter` to write each line out to a file using the platform-specific newline.  There is a shorter solution involving `string.replace(...)` (see comment by Unbeli), but it is slower and requires more memory.

Here is my solution - now made even simpler thanks to new features in Java 8:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String string = "This is lengthy string that contains many words. So\nI am wrapping it.";
    System.out.println(string);
    File file = new File("C:/Users/User/Desktop/text.txt");

    writeToFile(string, file);
}

private static void writeToFile(String string, File file) throws IOException {
    try (
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(string));
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    ) {
        reader.lines().forEach(line -> writer.println(line));
    }
}
```

Comment: uhm, stacking all these readers to do simple replacement? `string.replace("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));`

Comment: @unbeli, Replacement is quick if the String is short, for very lengthier strings, the above approach holds good. I have tested it though.

Comment: @unbeli - `String.replace()` requires creating a new object, which temporarily doubles the memory requirement, so it's not ideal for large amounts of data.  Though granted, with the data coming from a `JTextArea`, I can't imagine the string would be terribly large, so it would probably work just as well for the most part

Answer (score 7):

Please see the following question on how to appropriately handle newlines.

[How do I get a platform-dependent new line character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/java-how-do-i-get-a-platform-independent-new-line-character)

Basically you want to use

```
String newLineChar = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

and then use the newLineChar instead of "\n"

Answer (score 3):

I just ran your program, and adding a carriage return (`\r`) before your newline (`\n`) did the trick for me.

If you want to get a system independent line separator, one can be found in the system propery `line.separator`

```
String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String string = "This is lengthy string that contains many words. So" + separator
            + "I am wrapping it.";
```

Comment: I am getting String from JTextArea, do I have to manually identify the line breaks and insert `line.separator`? Is that the only way? :(

Comment: There may be better ways that than, but it sounds like that solution would work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to keep the carriage return characters from a Java string into a file. Just replace each break line character (which is recognized in java as: \n) as per the following statement:

TempHtml = TempHtml.replaceAll("\n", "\r\n");

Here is an code example,

```
        // When Execute button is pressed
        String TempHtml = textArea.getText();
        TempHtml = TempHtml.replaceAll("\n", "\r\n");
        try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/Temp/temp.html"))) {
            out.print(TempHtml);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(TempHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a BufferedWriter, you could also use the [.newline()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine--) method to re-add the newline based on your platform.

See this related question: [Strings written to file do not preserve line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199216/strings-written-to-file-do-not-preserve-line-breaks)