# Output entries to next line when writing to file

Tags: java, io, output, filewriter

My program writes entries of text to a file. Each entry is 4 word tokens written on a line. I want each entry to go on its own line, but the output I'm getting so far is:

```
abc1 abc1 abc1 abc1 abc2 abc2 abc2 abc2 abc3 abc3 abc3 abc3
```

(i.e. everything on the same line)

Here's my code:

```java
//targetFile = "C://...."
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("targetFile, true));
String s;
s = userInfo1;     //userInfo is an array of 4 word tokens
writer.append(s + " ");
writer.flush();
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Strings written to file using BufferedWriter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199216/strings-written-to-file-using-bufferedwriter).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
writer.write(s);
writer.newLine();
```

or use PrintWriter instead of BufferedWriter:

```
printWriter.println(s);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `writer.append(s + "\r\n");`

Comment: That's only appropriate for Windows. How about Unix and Linux?