# Not entering while loop

Tags: java, swing, file-io, io, jtextcomponent

I'm trying to write in a file whatever the user has written.
The file creates and all but the program fails to write whatever the user wrote from the program, to the file (The program is like notepad). It wont enter the while loop because the String line is null even if I write something in my program.

[image]

It seems it's returning null when I print the "line" String after using br.readLine().

[image]

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    bw.write(line);
    textArea.append("it worked");
}
```

Full code:

```
try {
    path = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath().replace('\\', '/') 
                                                                    + "/";
    File file = new File(path + File.separator + 
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "File name", "File") + ".txt");
    file.createNewFile();
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       bw.write(line);
       textArea.append("it worked");
    }
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
    textArea.append(path);
} catch(IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: There is no need to use BufferedReader and other such things; Java 8 has much better support for file IO. I am guessing you are using an outdated tutorial, try Googgling for more recent ways of IO. Things will work much better for you.

Comment: See also `JTextComponent` [`read(Reader, Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read-java.io.Reader-java.lang.Object-) & [`write(Writer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write-java.io.Writer-)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file.createNewFile();
. . .
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

The reader works from an empty file that just has been created. Of course `br.readLine()` will return null immediately since the file is empty.

Instead of the while loop, I would simply write:

```
bw.write(textArea.getText());
```

Comment: With this code if i write
"hello (new line)
 bye "
It prints "hellobye" in 1 line instead of "hello" and "bye" separated by a new line.

Comment: @Vincent You are probably using Windows. In this case, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199216/strings-written-to-file-do-not-preserve-line-breaks. While JTextArea uses \n as line breaks, Windows requires \r\n.