# BufferedWriter doesnt write JSON String correctly

Tags: java, json, string, writer

I wrote a code that gets a JSON text from a website and formats it so it is easier to read. My problem with the code is:

```
public static void gsonFile(){
  try {
    re = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dateiname));
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
    String uglyJSONString ="";
    uglyJSONString = re.readLine();
    JsonElement je = jp.parse(uglyJSONString);  
    String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);
    System.out.println(prettyJsonString);

    wr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dateiname));
    wr.write(prettyJsonString);

    wr.close();
    re.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

It correctly prints it into the console : http://imgur.com/B8MTlYW.png

But in my txt file it looks like this: http://imgur.com/N8iN7dv.png

What can I do so it correctly prints it into the file? (separated by new lines)

Comment: Sorry, edited it.

Comment: My bad: Those aren't images and shouldn't be posted as such. They should be posted as code-formatted text. Please go through the [help] to learn more about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gson uses `\n` as line delimiter (as can be seen in the `newline` method [here](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.java)).

Since **Notepad** does not understand `\n` you can either open your result file with another file editor (**Wordpad**, [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org), [Atom](https://atom.io), [Sublime Text](http://sublimetext.com), etc.) or replace the `\n` by `\r\n` before writing it:

```
prettyJsonString = prettyJsonString.replace("\n", "\r\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

FileReader and FileWriter are old utility classes that use the platform encoding. This gives non-portable files. And for JSON one ordinarily uses UTF-8.

```
Path datei = Paths.get(dateiname);
re = Files.newBufferedReader(datei, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Or

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(datei, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
// Without line endings as usual.
```

Or

```
String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(datei), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

And later:

```
Files.write(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is problem with your text editor. Not with text. It incorrectly process new line character.

I suppose it expect `CR LF`(Windows way) symbols and `Gson` generate only `LF` symbol (Unix way).

Comment: Try opening it with another editor (I know that you can see the whitespace characters with notepad++ for instance) and check the layout and whitespace there.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick search this topic might come handy.

[Strings written to file do not preserve line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199216/strings-written-to-file-do-not-preserve-line-breaks/35291147)

Also, opening in another editor like the others said will help too