# String should maintain Line break similar as TextArea

Tags: java, html, string

Input to textarea :(These 3 lines)

```
<textarea id="preM" rows="3" cols="10" style="resize: none; width:100%;">
</textarea><br/>
```

> This is example of textarea
>   This is new Line
>   Hello All

In JSP page I am retrieving the value of Text Area

```
String variableString = request.getParameter("preM");
System.out.println(variableString);
```

Output is coming as:

> This is example of textarea This is new Line Hello All

Expected output:

> This is example of textarea
>   This is new Line
>   Hello All

I have already tried

```
StringBuffer preM = new StringBuffer(request.getParameter("preM"));
int loc = (new String(preM)).indexOf('\n');
while(loc > 0){
  text.replace(loc, loc+1, "<BR>");
  loc = (new String(preM)).indexOf('\n');
}
out.println(preM);
```

But getting `loc=-1`.

Comment: Instead of  `id="preM"` you should use `name="preM"`
otherwise   `String variableString = request.getParameter("preM");`
 will print NULL

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to do that is to wrap the text into a `BufferedReader`, it can be used to iterate over the lines, and then use a `PrintWriter` to write each line out to a file using the platform-specific newline.

Please refer this SO : [Strings written to file do not preserve line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199216/strings-written-to-file-do-not-preserve-line-breaks)

There are 2 methods mentioned here, personally to save memory & to perform well over larger strings I would opt the `Bufferedreader` way.